# Discrete Maximum principle for variable coefficient Poisson equation

Tags: numerical-methods, maximum-principle

Consider the standard 5 point different approximation (centered difference for both the gradient and divergence operators) for the variable coefficient Poisson equation $$-\nabla \cdot(a\nabla v)=f$$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions, in a 2 dimensional rectangular region. We assume that $a(x,y)\geq a_0 >0$. The approximate solution $\{u_{i,j}\}$ satisfies a linear system $Au=b$.

Question: State and prove the maximum principle for the numerical solution $u_{i,j}$.

My attempt: **I am a bit unsure if the minus sign changes this problem. Maybe the $\geq$ should be a $\leq$ or something? Any help on this would be appreciated. I am also not sure if I am incorporating the variable coefficients correctly or not. Do I need to include them as I did or do I only consider the $u_{i,j}$?**

Statement: Assume that $-\nabla \cdot(a\nabla u_{i,j}) \geq 0$ for all $i=1,2,...,m$ and for all $j=1,2,...,n$. Let M be the maximum in the rectangular grid. Then, if $a_{i0,j0}u_{i0,j0}=M$ on any interior grid point, then $u_{i,j}=M$ for all interior and boundary points.

Proof: We have that $$M=-\nabla \cdot(a_{i0,j0}\nabla u_{i0,j0})\geq 0$$ for some point on the interior of the grid. Let h be delta x and k be delta y. 
$$\Rightarrow 0 \leq \frac{1}{h^2}\bigg(a_{i0-1,j0}u_{i0-1,j0}-2a_{i0,j0}u_{i0,j0} +a_{i0+1,j0}u_{i0+1,j0}\bigg) + \frac{1}{k^2}\bigg(a_{i0,j0-1}u_{i0,j0-1}-2a_{i0,j0}u_{i0,j0} +a_{i0,j0+1}u_{i0,j0+1}\bigg)$$

$$\Rightarrow 0 \leq \frac{1}{h^2}\bigg(a_{i0-1,j0}u_{i0-1,j0}-2M +a_{i0+1,j0}u_{i0+1,j0}\bigg) + \frac{1}{k^2}\bigg(a_{i0,j0-1}u_{i0,j0-1}-2M +a_{i0,j0+1}u_{i0,j0+1}\bigg)$$

So we must have the neighboring terms also equal to M or else the RHS will be smaller than 0. Repeat the argument for the neighbors until the entire region is shown to be M.

Comment: Let $\nabla_h$ be the discrete operator, I think you want to assume $-\nabla_h\cdot(a\nabla_h u)\le 0$ instead. When you expand out your discrete operator, it might get a little nasty but I believe the idea is still the same as the case for Poisson equation. So I think you are on the right track here.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. I appreciate it. Is there a specific reason to make it be <= 0 instead?

Comment: Would I maybe want to assume $\nabla_h(a \nabla_h u)\leq 0$? Because the initial assumption would be $-\nabla_h(a \nabla_h u)\geq 0$...

Comment: Well, one of them gives you the discrete maximum principle, and the other one gives you the discrete minimum principle. I believe it should be $-\nabla_h\cdot(a\nabla_hu)\le 0$ for discrete maximum principle, but I didn't write out the argument so maybe I am wrong and you are right (: What you should do is write down the five-point stencil for $\nabla\cdot(a\nabla u)$ and figure out which inequality gives you the discrete maximum principle.

Comment: Sounds good. I will do that. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @CheeHan After looking into this I agree with you on the choice for the max principle. Thank you again!